# Date SQL Server join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table with records of data activation and terminations.
I only get `subscriber`, `imsi`, `date`, `package status` and `data package` from the server. Now I need to join the activated and the terminated records.

I have no clue where to start or how to achieve this.

Can anyone assist me with this?

This
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoRc0.png

Should become this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue1mA.png

Comment: what do you mean by **Join** activated and terminated records.

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2012 or higher, take a look at the `LAG()` or `LEAD()` analytic functions.  If you're not on 2012, then [things get complicated](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/).

Comment: No I am on SQL Server 2008, indeed i could have used those functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT ANSWER IS HERE:

```
SELECT t1.subscriber, t1.imsi, t1.pakket, t1.datum, t1.data_pakket, t1.pakket_status, 
(SELECT min(datum) FROM mytable t2
 WHERE t2.datum > t1.datum
AND pakket_status='TERMINATED') AS end_date
FROM mytable t1
WHERE t1.pakket_status='ACTIVATED';
```

SQLFIDDLE FOR PROOF: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4f64/12

Comment: I'm looking into it more but seems like sqlfiddle is down or something

Comment: I just fixed your problem no need :D

Comment: just added my query to your fiddle and it seems to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be367/3

Comment: @Wishaal let me know if it worked on your actual data, if you need any feedback I'll be on in about 3-4 hours for a bit so you can ask if something isn't clear

Comment: i need to do one more thing. I have placed and id field in the table which is auto increment. How can i get the id of the activated and terminated row?

Comment: t1.id, t2.id in the select statement